# How to add specific Windows Services in a Zabbix Server to monitor with email alerts?

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

I Installed Zabbix in one of my Linux Server. I added the default Windows Template for monitoring, but I am not able to add some other services. 
Is it possible to add email alerts for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Default windows templates will do basic tasks such monitoring hard disk, processor, memory ...
They come with set of predefined rules, I suggest you to modify them for your own needs.
If you need monitoring of specific services on windows like IIS, MSSQL, etc. You will need to download and install additional templates and configure them.

For e-mail notification you will need to define media type (email) first. SMTP parameters must be correct. Than you need to link defined media (email) to specific user.
Here is a some helpful link:
[Zabbix email setings](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/quickstart/email_settings)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am able to monitor Specific service by creating ""

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to monitor Specific service by creating "New Item".  But while adding 2 email ID's in the "SMTP email", it's not working means the Alerts are not coming to the given Email ID's. Kindly help.